# How to get users via API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, async.js

There are two models in my project: applicants and companies.
Creating, authentificating and deleting users happens by the same API.
So, I have a middleware, that resolves user model by its session ID. For example, it will usefull to get current user, where first we recieve user by its ID and then send it. 
My code is below:

```
getUserByID(req, res, next) {
if (req.session.user_id) {
  async.race([
    (callback) => {
      Applicant.findOne({_id: req.session.user_id})
        .catch(() => {
          return apiHelper.handleError(res, 'Unknown error', 'Can not find user')
        })
        .then(callback)
    },
    (callback) => {
      Company.findOne({_id: req.session.user_id})
        .catch(() => {
          return apiHelper.handleError(res, 'Unknown error', 'Can not find user')
        })
        .then(callback)
    }
  ],
    (user) => {
      if (user) {
        res.locals.currentUser = user;
        next()
      }
      return apiHelper.handleError(res, 'User not found', 'Can not log in', 400)
    });
} else {
  apiHelper.handleError(res, 'Not authed', 'Please, log in', 400)
}}
```

I have test to this route, and problem is that test randomly passes, randomly not. I think it's because I use module async, or smthg with it

Comment: What is your reason for using `async.race()`? A user is either an applicant OR a company?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of your final callback is an error object (like with most `async.js` functions). See the [example](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#race).

Also when you do

```
if (user) {
    res.locals.currentUser = user;
    next();
}
return apiHelper.handleError(res, 'User not found', 'Can not log in', 400); // *
```

If a user is found, the last line will still be executed. Make sure to do `return next();` or use `if/else`.

I would refactor your code as below. The beauty of `async.js` is that you can consolidate your error handling in one place.

```
getUserByID(req, res, next) {
    if (req.session.user_id) {
        async.race([
            callback => Applicant.findById(req.session.user_id, callback),
            callback => Company.findById(req.session.user_id, callback)
        ], 
        (err, user) => {
            // note the use of return to prevent execution of any following lines
            if (err)
                return apiHelper.handleError(res, 'Unknown error', 'Can not find user', 500);
            if (!user)
                return apiHelper.handleError(res, 'User not found', 'Can not log in', 400); 
            res.locals.currentUser = user;
            next();
        });
    } else {
        apiHelper.handleError(res, 'Not authed', 'Please, log in', 400)
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
getUserByID(req, res, next) {
if (req.session.user_id) {
  async.race([
    (callback) => {
      Applicant.findOne({_id: req.session.user_id})
        .catch(() => {
          return apiHelper.handleError(res, 'Unknown error', 'Can not find user')
        })
        .then(callback)
    },
    (callback) => {
      Company.findOne({_id: req.session.user_id})
        .catch(() => {
          return apiHelper.handleError(res, 'Unknown error', 'Can not find user')
        })
        .then(callback)
    }
  ],
    (user) => {
      if (user) {
        res.locals.currentUser = user;
        return next(); // added return statement
      }
      return apiHelper.handleError(res, 'User not found', 'Can not log in', 400)
    });
} else {
  apiHelper.handleError(res, 'Not authed', 'Please, log in', 400)
}}
```